# What kind of aircraft are currently being used by Boulder County to fight wildfires?

Tags: aircraft-identification, firefighting

I was wondering, what kind of aircraft are currently being used by Boulder County to fight wildfires? For example, see photo attached of a plane dropping flame retardant on a wildfire over Left-Hand Canyon in Boulder, Colorado.

[image: plane dropping flame retardant on a wildfire over Left-Hand Canyon in Boulder, Colorado]

I would appreciate any insight anyone can share on this. Thank you.

Comment: More importantly, why is he gear down during the retardant drop?

Comment: @FreeMan I'm guessing a sudden unloading and subsequent pull-up maneuver could cause the gear to gravity drop. Might also help avoid overspeeding.

Comment: @FreeMan Apparently, it's written into the STC that they need gear down during drops, supposedly to prevent stalling. I didn't look up the STC myself, but here's an article: https://fireaviation.com/2017/09/16/the-faa-requires-ericksons-md-87s-to-drop-retardant-with-landing-gear-down/. I also seem to remember reading in one of the forums that people felt it was a silly requirement.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a [McDonnell Douglas MD-87](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_MD-80#MD-87), specifically one from [Erickson Aero Tanker](http://www.eatanker.com/).

[image]
<sup>[Source: eatanker.com](http://www.eatanker.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the Erickson MD-87, the [Avro RJ85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_146) from [Neptune Aviation Services](https://neptuneaviation.com/operations-2/) is also being used to fight the wildfires west of Denver. They are currently based at [Rocky Mountain Municipal Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_Mountain_Metropolitan_Airport).

I caught a photo of one on the ground just a few weeks ago.

[image: Neptune Aviation RJ-85 #41]

[image: OpenADSB screenshot of firefighting RJ85]

Answer (score 1):

It's an MD-87, the shortened version of the MD-80 series. It's not operated by Boulder County, it's operated by Erickson, which also operates a number of S-64 Skycrane helicopters.